# how to run getElementsByClassName on a node rather than the whole element

Tags: javascript

I am curious to find out if there's an easy way to search for children of node `X` without actually having to loop through every child and their children and the children of the children and so on. Something like `X.getElementsByClassName`. Is there such thing? I just want to point out that this is regarding pure natural javascript without any libraries or frameworks.

Comment: Have you tried `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].getElementsByClassName`? What does that come up with?

Comment: How could this have not worked when I tested it the first time, but now after I asked the question, of course, works! Doh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **`document.getElementsByClassName`**
>   Returns a set of elements which have all the given class names. When called on the document object, the complete document is searched, including the root node. You may also call getElementsByClassName on any element; it will return only elements which are descendants of the specified root element with the given class names.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: Documentation FTW. You might also want to check some specs, like http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#getelementsbyclassname0